# Global Structure array gives a NullReferenceException

Tags: .net, vb.net, nullreferenceexception

Here is the definition of the structure

```
Structure Ct

    Public name As String

    Structure Pt
        Public identity As String
    End Structure

    Public Pty() As Pt

End Structure


Public Cty() As Main.Ct
```

This is declared in a module called main.

Then this piece of code, located in a subroutine in another class is run

```
Dim i As Integer = 1
    For Each item As String In cataList.Items
        'cataList is a listbox
        Cty(i).name = item
        i += 1
    Next
```

It throws a nullReferenceException.

What is missing? I need the structure to be global.

Comment: Duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array is declared but not instanced as the linked dupe describes.  But an array of structures is not the most efficient way to do what you are trying.

```
Friend Class Ct                     ' cries out for a meaningful name        

    Public Property Name As String
    Private _identities As New List(of String)    ' ie "Pty"

    ' a ctor to create with the name prop
    Public Sub New(n As String)
        Name = n
    End Sub

    Public Sub AddIdentity(id As String)
         _identities.Add(id)
    End Sub

    ' get one
    Public Function GetIdentity(index As Integer) As String
         Return _identities(index)
    End Sub

    ' get all
    Public Function Identities As String()
        Return _identities.ToArray
    End If

    ' and so on for Count, Clear...  
End Class
```

Then a list of these things:

```
' as (elegantly) described in the NRE link, NEW creates an instance:
Friend Cty As New List(Of Ct)
```

Then fill the List from the ListBox:

```
For Each s As String In cataList.Items
    Cty.Add(New CT(s))             ' create CT with name and add to list
Next
```

The more you work with Lists and Collections, the more you will appreciate how much more flexible and powerful they are.  For instance, there might not be a need to manually populate the `ListBox` at all.  Use the `DataSource` property to bind the list to the listbox; this is more efficient because you *map* rather than *copy* the data to the UI control:

```
' tell the listbox which property on your class (Type) to display
cataList.DisplayMember = "Name"
cataList.DataSource = Cty
```

For cases where you want/need to copy the data:

```
For n As Integer = 0 to Cty.Count-1
    cataList.Items.Add(Cty(n).Name)
Next
```

Or:

```
For Each item As Ct In cty          
    cataList.Items.Add(item.Name)
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

cataList.Items is made up of listviewitems instead of strings. That may be causing problems. In addition, Cty has no members when it is declared.

Try this:

```
ReDim Cty(cataList.Items.Count-1)

For Each item As ListViewItem In cataList.Items
    'cataList is a listbox
    Cty(i).name = item.Text
    i += 1
Next
```

You could also use a list (with .add) instead of an array to avoid the redim.